# Conditional Statetment to test if user input is integer or decimal

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an application for determining the area of a rectangle. The user enters the width and the length via two text fields and the result is displayed via button click. I want the user to be able to enter either decimal or integer values.

**Front-end**:

```
<div>
         Enter Value 1: <asp:TextBox ID="length_txt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
         Enter Value 2: <asp:TextBox ID="width_txt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
         <asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" Text="submit" onclick="button1_Click" /><br />
         <asp:Label ID="area_lbl" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <br />
    </div>
```

**back-end**

```
protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //area_lbl.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(length_txt.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(width_txt.Text));
        area_lbl.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDecimal(length_txt.Text) * Convert.ToDecimal(width_txt.Text));
    }
```

...my question is, how do I create an if-statement that will test if the input boxes has an integer or decimal value?

Comment: Just test if it's divisible by 1?

Comment: Why would you need this distinction? All integer values can be represented as Decimal, so why not just always use Decimal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Never ever** use `Convert.To<SomePrimitiveTypeHere>` on user input.
If the input can't be converted you will get an exception.
Every primitive type in the .Net framework have a `TryParse` method - it will return `true` if converted successfully and false otherwise.

So, what your code should look like is something like this:

```
protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int intLength, intWidth;
    Decimal decimalLength , decimalWidth;
    if(int.TryParse(length_txt.Text, out intLength) && int.TryParse(width_txt.Text, out intWidth))
    {
        area_lbl.Text = (intLength * intWidth).ToString();
    }
    else if(Decimal.TryParse(length_txt.Text, out decimalLength) && Decimal.TryParse(width_txt.Text, out decimalWidth))
    {
        area_lbl.Text = (decimalLength * decimalWidth).ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        area_lbl.Text = "Invalid input!";
    }
}
```

However, as NineBerry wrote in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48429052/conditional-statetment-to-test-if-user-input-is-integer-or-decimal/48429191#comment83848943_48429052), every integer value can be represented as Decimal, you can ignore the first condition and simply write this:

```
    if(Decimal.TryParse(length_txt.Text, out decimalLength) && Decimal.TryParse(width_txt.Text, out decimalWidth))
    {
        area_lbl.Text = (decimalLength * decimalWidth).ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        area_lbl.Text = "Invalid input!";
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Zohar Peled for the advise and the example.

Comment: Glad to help :-)